# ElasticSearch 5 adding context to SuggestionBuilders

Tags: java, elasticsearch, search-suggestion

I am working on ES5 through java, and am trying to add context to a CompletionSuggestionBuilder. I have a map of String objects that need to be added. The code I have so far is -

```
Map<String, String> context = ...
CompletionSuggestionBuilder csb = SuggestBuilders.completionSuggestion(field).text(value).size(count);
```

How do I add context objects to `csb`? I think the method to use is -

```
csb.contexts(Map<String, List<? extends ToXContent>> queryContexts)
```

But I don't know how to get from my map to the map to pass as arguments to the contexts method.

Answer (score 11):

You can create `Map<String, List<? extends ToXContent>>` like this;

```
Collections.singletonMap("cat", Arrays.asList(CategoryQueryContext.builder().setCategory("cat0").setBoost(3).build(), CategoryQueryContext.builder().setCategory("cat1").build()))
```

I think currently supported types that extend `ToXContext` are `CategoryQueryContext` and `GeoQueryContext`

The strange thing here is that if I create a local variable and pass it to the `contexts` it does not work. So, I just passed it directly to the contexts it does work.

Full example would be like this:

```
CompletionSuggestionBuilder prefix = SuggestBuilders.completionSuggestion(FIELD).prefix("sugg").contexts(Collections.singletonMap("cat", Arrays.asList(CategoryQueryContext.builder().setCategory("cat0").setBoost(3).build(), CategoryQueryContext.builder().setCategory("cat1").build())));
```

It is all written in their test cases. You can take a look at it:
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/core/src/test/java/org/elasticsearch/search/suggest/ContextCompletionSuggestSearchIT.java#L290

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for this. As an FYI, if you want it to work with a local variable (i.e. without getting shouted at by Java generic checks), you need to do: `final Map<String, List<? extends ToXContent>> contexts = ...`